# PhP Footer error

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, footer

Hello i was trying change the footer of my wordpress site to somthing else. I thought i was just changing the words but i some how messed up the code. I don't know enough about php to fix was i did

Error is on line 40

```
<?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_back_to_top', 'false' ) ) : ?>

    <span class="et_pb_scroll_top et-pb-icon"></span>

<?php endif;

if ( ! is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ) : ?>

            <footer id="main-footer">
                <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>


        <?php
            if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer-menu' ) ) : ?>

                <div id="et-footer-nav">
                    <div class="container">
                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
                                'depth'          => '1',
                                'menu_class'     => 'bottom-nav',
                                'container'      => '',
                                'fallback_cb'    => '',
                            ) );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- #et-footer-nav -->

            <?php endif; ?>

                <div id="footer-bottom">
                    <div class="container clearfix">
                <?php
                    if ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_footer_social_icons', true ) ) {
                        get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'footer' );
                    }
                ?>

                        <p id="footer-info"><?php printf( __( (changed this) %1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'Divi' ), '<a href="http://www.elegantthemes.com" title="Premium WordPress Themes">Elegent themes (and this) </a>', '<a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a>' ); ?></p>
                    </div>  <!-- .container -->
                </div>
            </footer> <!-- #main-footer -->
        </div> <!-- #et-main-area -->

<?php endif; // ! is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ?>

    </div> <!-- #page-container -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I really have no idea what is wrong. I understand html. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please identify line 40? Also, please tell us what error you received.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing single quote in the code, please use following code, I have fixed the code by restoring to original Divi code line

```
<?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_back_to_top', 'false' ) ) : ?>

<span class="et_pb_scroll_top et-pb-icon"></span>

<?php endif;

if ( ! is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ) : ?>

        <footer id="main-footer">
            <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>


    <?php
        if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer-menu' ) ) : ?>

            <div id="et-footer-nav">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
                            'depth'          => '1',
                            'menu_class'     => 'bottom-nav',
                            'container'      => '',
                            'fallback_cb'    => '',
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- #et-footer-nav -->

        <?php endif; ?>

            <div id="footer-bottom">
                <div class="container clearfix">
            <?php
                if ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_footer_social_icons', true ) ) {
                    get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'footer' );
                }
            ?>

<p id="footer-info"><?php printf( __( 'Designed by %1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'Divi' ), '<a href="http://www.elegantthemes.com" title="Premium WordPress Themes">Elegant Themes</a>', '<a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a>' ); ?></p>

                    </div>  <!-- .container -->
                </div>
            </footer> <!-- #main-footer -->
        </div> <!-- #et-main-area -->

<?php endif; // ! is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ?>

    </div> <!-- #page-container -->
```

Specifically you have omitted the single quote from this line

```
<p id="footer-info"><?php printf( __( 'Designed by
```

See single quote just after __( , that you had omitted from your original code.